# How to keep hyperlinks with Abiword when creating PDF?

Tags: pdf, abiword

When I write a document in Abiword and then print it to a file my hyperlinks get lost.

It seems that LibreOffice can export PDF with hyperlinks. When I opened my document that I created with Abiword the hyperlinks where included in the text, but kind of not activated. When I clicked on the text to add a hyperlink that I thought was missing it was already there, but was not beeing exported to the PDF and also not shown with underscore in LibreOffice.

Maybe the problem is how Abiword saves the hyperlinks in its text.

Comment: Are you trying to file a bug report?

Comment: :) I am trying to find out if it is just a matter of settings in Abiword.